# How can I specify at which moment a CTkFrame Class should utilize a global variable so that it fetches once it has been populated by another class?

Tags: python, class, user-interface, customtkinter

I am trying to build a GUI with CTk that fetches a material name as input from a user and uses this to make recommendations for better alternatives. Currently I am stuck trying to figure out how to make 5 CTkEntry boxes display the values for the properties of said material, after the input has been provided, but I struggle with the way the classes are instanced, as the Entry boxes are fetching a global list variable to pull data from before it has been populated.

Essentially 4 pieces of code work together, an App Class that creates the interface and features the global variable material_properties as an empty list, a UserInput Class that takes input from the user on an Entry box and uses that as an argument for a db_entry_matching function in another file that checks against an existing DB to see if the input matches anything in the DB, and if it does extracts the material property information. Once that information has been extracted it populated material_properties with it. And finally DBMatching is the Class that features the EntryBoxes to display the values for each of the material properties from the now populated global list.

However, since all the classes are executed at the same time it, DBMatching fetches the list when its not populated and so the Entry boxes are displayed as empty. So how can I make it so that DBMatching fetches the list only after the button inside UserInput has ran the command to check the user input against the DB? I can provide code examples if my explanation is not clear enough.